# In an HTML form input, why is the method called GET if data is being "sent/submitted"?

Tags: html, http, post, methods, get

I read on SoloLearn that the method attribute of an input tag within a form can be set to GET or POST. If both methods are sending data to another location, is an HTTP GET being used somehow? I thought GET was used to retrieve data, not send it. Can anyone help me understand, please?

Comment: GET can not send a `body` of data with it, but it does have valid uses. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET

Comment: Both methods are used to send an HTTP request that results in data being sent back from the server. There are just some differences in the way that the request is sent and how/what kind of information goes into each type of request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All HTTP requests involve sending something to the server.

A GET request is designed to be used to ask for something.

If you GET `http://example.com/` then you ask for the root document for that site.

If you submit the form at `https://duckduckgo.com/` then your request is to GET `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=example&t=hf&ia=web`. You are asking for the search results for the keyword "example".

Comment: I see now! It's like saying to the server "Use the data I am giving you to GET a resource". Thank you.